# Java Apache POI HSSF CellRangeAddressList

Tags: java, excel, apache, deprecated

I am trying to set up an app for users to download an Excel spreadsheet to insert data and I want one of the cells in the sheet to have a data validation with drop down list.

I am following the guidance on the Apache POI site (https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Validation) which includes guidance to utilize the CellRangeAddressList data type and constructor.

Here is the full code I am using from the Apache site:

```
  HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
  HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Data Validation");
  CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(
    0, 0, 0, 0);
  DVConstraint dvConstraint = DVConstraint.createExplicitListConstraint(
    new String[]{"10", "20", "30"});
  DataValidation dataValidation = new HSSFDataValidation
    (addressList, dvConstraint);
  dataValidation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(false);
  sheet.addValidationData(dataValidation);
```

However, when I use it in my code, Netbeans is giving me a deprecated API error.  Is there a more recent and/or appropriate datatype that I should be using.

Answer (score 0):

which package you have imported for the Class `CellRangeAddressList`
You might be using this package :

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.CellRangeAddressList;
```

try below package for the same class :

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddressList;
```